# Magento 1 : Sort Product Listing By New?

Tags: product, frontend, product-sorting

Working on magento 1 website.

I want to sort the product sorting by new in all product categories. So that when any new product is added that shows on first.

Can i be please guided how can same be done.

Comment: You can sort the field `created_at`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite **Toolbar** block in your custom module

> app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
...
...
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_list_toolbar>Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
...
...
```

Now create your custom block which rewrites the **Toolbar** block.

> app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Block/Catalog/Product/List/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='new'){
                $this->_collection->setOrder('entity_id','desc');
            }
            else {
                $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setDefaultOrder($field)
    {
        if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$field])) {
            $new = ['new' => 'New'];
            $this->_availableOrder = $new + $this->_availableOrder;
            //$this->_orderField = $field;
            $this->_orderField = 'new';
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```